# Neo4j/CYPHER: How can I query some properties from a node, its relationships and target node efficiently?

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, cypher

I want to query for a set of nodes a subset of their attributes, their relationships and the target nodes with some of their attributes (from Java with CYPHER via REST). My idea was the following:

```
MATCH a WHERE id(a) IN {ids}
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN id(a), a.name, a.attr1, r.attr2, id(b), b.name
```

Now I get a "row" for every relationship, but it contains the the data for every node "a" multiple times.

Is there a better way to make such a query so that attribute(s) for the nodes "a" are transferred only once? One idea is to make 2 separate queries, but if the WHERE condition is a little bit more complex, it may be executed twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use collect function.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-collect

```
MATCH a WHERE id(a) IN {ids}
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN id(a), a.name, a.attr1, collect([r.attr2, id(b), b.name])
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @frant.hartm is totally correct! But, if you want to use a slightly different approach you may consider the following:

Imagine the following graph:

```
create 
    (p1:Employee {name:"John"})-[:works_at]->(e1:Employer {name:"Microsoft"}),
    (p1)-[:works_at]->(e2:Employer {name:"Oracle"}),
    (p2:Employee {name:"Jim"})-[:works_at]->(e1),
    (p2)-[:works_at]->(e2)
return p1, p2, e1, e2

// RESULT:
// (Jim)-works_at->(Microsoft)
// (Jim)-works_at->(Oracle)
// (John)-works_at->(Microsoft)
// (John)-works_at->(Oracle)
```

In order to `COLLECT` for a nice output format you can also use **literal maps** as in the example below:

```
MATCH 
    (a:Employee)-[r:works_at]->(e:Employer) 
WITH 
    a, 
    r, 
    COLLECT({name:e.name, id:ID(e)}) AS employers
WITH 
    a, 
    COLLECT({ type : type(r), employers : employers}) AS employerRels
WITH 
    { name : a.name, id: ID(a), employers : employerRels} AS employee
RETURN 
    employee
```

Then, the awesome result will nicely formatted JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "Jim",
  "id": 227,
  "employers": [
    {
      "type": "works_at",
      "employers": [
        {
          "name": "Oracle",
          "id": 226
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "works_at",
      "employers": [
        {
          "name": "Microsoft",
          "id": 225
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "John",
  "id": 224,
  "employers": [
    {
      "type": "works_at",
      "employers": [
        {
          "name": "Oracle",
          "id": 226
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "works_at",
      "employers": [
        {
          "name": "Microsoft",
          "id": 225
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```